# Right adjoints preserve j-dense monos

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Let’s assume $\epsilon$ is a topos and $L:\epsilon\longrightarrow \epsilon$ and $R:\epsilon \longrightarrow\epsilon$ are two adjoint functors such that $L\dashv R$. Now, let j be a Lawvere-Tierney topology in $\epsilon$. Let $m:M\longrightarrow M’$ be a j-dense mono. Now, since R preserves limits, it preserves pullbacks and I guess this gives us that $Rm:RM\longrightarrow RM’$ is also a j-dense mono. Is it true?

Comment: But need a right adjoint preserve the subobject classifier or the topology on it?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I guess you are right. In my idea we need that right adjoint preserve subobject classifier which I do not know it is true or not.

Comment: @PouyaLayeghi It will generally not. Just think about the inclusion functor of a topos of sheaves into the corresponding presheaf topos $i: \mathcal{E} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}$. Then $i$ is right adjoint to the sheafification functor, but $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}$ will (generally) have different subobject classifiers.

Comment: @MarkKamsma by previous comment, I paid attention to this example. But what about here?